# How to use DB::insert as a prepared statement LARAVEL

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to make my insert query protected against sql injection. But I am having issues getting this to work. any ideas?
I have tried several things.

```
 $bullets = Input::get('bullet_content');
        $product_id = Input::get('product_id');
        $user_id = Input::get('user_id');
        $retailer_id = Input::get('retailer_id');
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        foreach ($bullets as $bullet){


            $query = "'INSERT INTO bullets(product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) 
                        VALUES('?','?','?','?','?','?')', [$product_id,$user_id,$bullet,'N',$date,$date]";


                        DB::insert($query);
        }
        return back()->with('message','Features add successfully!');
```

When I try this I get the following errror:

```
SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (SQL: 'INSERT INTO bullets(product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) VALUES('?','?','?','?','?','?')', [1,1,can't,'N',2017-11-10 16:28:44,2017-11-10 16:28:44])
```

I have also tried:

```
 $bullets = Input::get('bullet_content');
        $product_id = Input::get('product_id');
        $user_id = Input::get('user_id');
        $retailer_id = Input::get('retailer_id');
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        foreach ($bullets as $bullet){


            $query = "'INSERT INTO bullets(product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) 
                        VALUES('?','?','?','?','?','?')' ";
            $values = [$product_id,$user_id,$bullet,'N',$date,$date];

                        DB::insert($query,$values);
        }
        return back()->with('message','Features add successfully!');
```

and got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT INTO bullets(product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) VALUES('. (SQL: 'INSERT INTO bullets(product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) VALUES('1','1','can't','N','2017-11-10 16:33:43','2017-11-10 16:33:43')' )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to quote question marks. Furthermore you can initialize **$query** before loop and use it as your prepared query inside the **foreach**:

```
$bullets = Input::get('bullet_content');
$product_id = Input::get('product_id');
$user_id = Input::get('user_id');
$retailer_id = Input::get('retailer_id');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "INSERT INTO bullets (product_id, user_id,bullet_content, bullet_deleted, created_at, updated_at) 
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
foreach ($bullets as $bullet) {
    $values = [$product_id,$user_id,$bullet,'N',$date,$date];
    DB::insert($query, $values);
}
return back()->with('message','Features add successfully!');
```

Comment: Well, there it is. Thanks!